# Building a custom List

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to generate a list from an object using an ArrayAdapter. The result Looks like:

Item A   (3)
Item B   (1)
Item C   (0)

The number in brackets represents the amount of items that are behind that file. I want to Display an Image whenever there is a 1 in brackets - in this case only for item B.

I have an Attribute Image available that is only set true when the item has a 1.

However, when I'm creating the list, it creates everywhere the Image, except in Item C. I have created a short log to try to understand the reason and found out, that `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {`
 method is called up to 11 times... though the 1st 3 should be enough. when i modified my if clause that it should set imageavailable to false when an item is detected - only the 1st item had a Picture. can anyone help me out? ( i also tryed to make if(imageavailable&number==1) resulting in the same result - 1st 2 have a picture

Answer (score 0):

You should be managing the adapter, not adding logic to getView. You logic for handling the adapter should be in its own method. For example:

```
ArrayList<Drawable> adapter = new ArrayList<Drawable>();

void constructAdapter(List<Drawable>... drawables, int sizeFilter) {
    if (drawables != null) {
        for (List<Drawable> l : drawables) {
            if (drawable.size() == sizeFilter) {
                for (int i = 0; i < sizeFilter) {
                    adapter.add(l.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then from here you would pass the adapter list into your array adapter.

Note: I used drawable as my example, since you said images. This could be whatever you want, so long as you just change the logic to handle that particular data set.

Comment: this doesnt help me to build <br>Item A (3)
<br>Item B (1)  PICTURE
<br>Item C (0)
<br>Item D (2)
<br>Item E (1)  PICTURE as far as i can see; i wanted to write more, but im getting a formatting error - my source code performed well on a real device so i have no clue what the Problem is